# Поле со списком не отправляется в БД

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "regauth") or die("Error!!!");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    header("location: ../../");

if($_GET['link'] === 'logout'){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../../");
}
  $len=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameselect']));
    if(isset($_POST['do-len'])){
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (len) VALUES ('$len') ");  
 }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Личный кабинет</title>
</head>

<body>
<div><?php echo "Привет, ".$_SESSION['user'][1]; ?> | <a href="index.php?link=logout">Выйти</a>
</div>
<h3>Создание заявки</h3>
<form  method="post">
<p><select size="3" name="nameselect" multiple>
    <option value="Тест1">Тест1</option>
    <option value="Тест1">Тест2</option>
    <option value="Тест3">Тест3</option>
   </select></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="do-len"value="Отправить"></p>
   </form>
   <h3>Просмотр своих записей на курсы</h3>
<!--   <?php
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from `users` where 'len' "); 
/*
символ '*' указывает, что нужно выбрать все столбцы
если Вам нужен один или несколько столбцов, укажите какие
это сократит нагрузку на MySQL и время вывода информации
например, нам нужны только заголовок и текст
*/

$result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

# выводим результат
print "$result[len]";

   ?>

    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: есть ли какая то ошибка? что показывает var_dump($len); перед mysqli_query?

Comment: Тест1 ошибки нет, я вот думаю может я бд использовал не правильный тип?уместно ли использовать  тип varchar в таблице PHP MY ADMIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо
`<select name="nameselect" multiple>`

укажите, что вы ожидаете массив:
`<select name="nameselect[]" multiple>`

Затем получайте его и подставляйте в запрос:

```
// получим массив с выбранными именами
$names = $_POST['nameselect'];

// получаем строку вида: INSERT INTO users (len) VALUES ('Тест1'), ('Тест3'):
$query = "INSERT INTO users (len) VALUES ('".implode("'), ('", $names)."')";

// выполняем запрос
mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

---

**Внимание**, это упрощенный пример. Использование в реальном приложении может привести к проблемам с безопасностью.

Comment: Вроде сделал как вы сказали но в бд опять не отправляется...$formdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
  // $len=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameselect']));
$names = $formdata['nameselect'];
$names_str = implode(', ', $names);
   if(isset($_POST['do-len'])){
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (len) VALUES ('$names_str') ");  
 }

Comment: (var_dump показывает тест 1 перед mysqli_query?)$formdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
  // $len=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameselect']));
$names = $formdata['nameselect'];
$names_str = implode(', ', $names);
   if(isset($_POST['do-len'])){
      var_dump($names_str);
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (len) VALUES ('$names_str') ");  
 }

Comment: Конечно, у INSERT синтаксис другой. Вам что нужно-то в итоге, получить записи где есть эти имена или вставить в базу несколько имен?

Comment: Если нужно только получить данные, почему вы вообще упоминаете про INSERT - вставку данных?  Подставлять в запрос нужно так: `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE len IN ('".implode("', '", $names)."') ";`

Comment: мне нужно допустим я тест 1 выбираю и что бы отправилось в бд запись со значением тест1

Comment: а select я закоментировал это я потом использую у меня пока проблема что в бд не отправляются значения

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, если нужно так. Но вообще ваш вот этот пример: `INSERT INTO users (len) VALUES ('$names_str')`  - запрос так не стоится, нужно перечислять каждое значение в скобках, а не все в одни скобки пихать. Вы сначала в *phpmyadmin* запрос бы лучше выполнили чтобы убедиться, что он работает, а уж потом пытались его в *php* составить.

Comment: спасибо вам большое вы мне помогли,3 месяца не программмировал забыл синтаксис малек)

Comment: Не за что, хорошо, что разобрались )

Comment: Да, и если вам нужно массив предварительно проверить на символы и пробелы или что-то еще, вы можете использовать *array_map*: `$names = array_map(function($val){ return htmlspecialchars(trim($val)); }, $names);`

Comment: учту но я новичок и то что я написал более понятно и запоминающи лично мне да и выполняет свою функцию поэтому пока буду использовать ее,но все равно спс)Я про это  $len=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nameselect']));

Comment: у вас это уже не сработает, потому что раньше в `$_POST['nameselect']` была строка, а теперь - массив (если вы сделали так, как написано -  `nameselect[]` и `multiple` )

Comment: я оставил все как было но вы нашли мою ошибку я лишь ее исправил поэтому работает)